# To speed up data refresh should I create a view or use query folding?

Tags: sqlite, view, powerbi, refresh, folding

I have an SQLite database of 5GB which gets updated few times a day and is used to refresh a PowerBI dashboard. While below 1GB I could refresh the dashboard in under a minute, but now takes around 20 minutes.

1. Should I create views so merges, joins, etc. are made in the view instead of loading the table itself and using Power Query to perform data manipulation?
2. Should I use incremental refresh? Is it possible in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement views on the database side in this case. This is in my eyes the benefit of having control of the DB yourself - pushing these data transforms to the DB instead of tinkering in Power Query is a major benefit.

When the views are set up, work on incremental refresh if the SQLITE3 connector supports it, but if it doesn't use the "regular" SQL Database connector it may not do so, according to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/native-query-folding#supported-data-connectors).

Comment: Hi @Marcus, I implemented a view in the DB of my two most "Power Query" intensive queries, and the time it takes to get the whole dashboard refreshed went down from 15min to 8min. Now on to incremental refresh.

Answer (score 1):

5GB is tiny in size and your refreshes should not be overly long. How complicated are your queries and what kind of transformations are you doing?

I would first look at making sure you're not breaking query folding. Seemingly simple steps do not always support folding but by rearranging them you can ensure folding happens and have a drastic effect on refresh times. Check at what stage folding is breaking and see if you can move things around.

Next, I'd look at moving your transformations upstream to a view (Roche's maxim).

Incremental refresh will also work so it is up to you really to pick from the available options.

Comment: I have 29 tables in my database, all of the columns from the database are using a "N/A" data type, so I have to change the data type of all the columns using Power Query. Also I do a few merges and joins between those tables. Yes I pretty much break the query folding right at the beginning in all the queries I made in PowerBI. I'm thinking about creating views for each query I use in PowerBI, where all the transformation are already there, so I pretty much just import the view and use it in PowerBI, no changes/transformation. Now I'm wondering how much faster the end result will be.

Comment: Changing data types does sometimes break folding (especially dates). Can you not move that step lower down and do other transformations first?

Comment: Hi @David, that's exactly what is happening, since dates are treated as TEXT in SQLite3, whenever I import one table which uses date, I have to convert it to date in power query, and that breaks folding.

Comment: Why can't you convert to date at the end of the query?

Comment: I can modify the string to fit the ISO format dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm, would this be enough for PowerBI to assign the data type as date when it refreshes the data?

Comment: That is a datetime. Just move it to the end of your query as I originally suggested.